# Bundle the JAR File into an App Package with Preloader JavaFx

Tags: java, ant, package, preloader

I'm trying to create an app package with preloader class using ant. With the following build.xml file the app is successfully created. After double click on Viewer.app the preloader screen doesn't appear. When I start the application directly with java -jar Viewer.jar the preloader screen can be ssen on windows os and mac os.

```
<taskdef name="bundleapp"
         classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
         classpath="classlib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />

<target name="bundle-MyProject">
    <bundleapp outputdirectory="dist"
        name="Viewer"
        displayname="MyProject Viewer"
        identifier="MyProject.Start"
        mainclassname="MyProject.Start"
        icon="classlib/MyProject.icns">

    <runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}" />
    <classpath file="dist/Viewer.jar" />

    <classpath dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar" />

    </bundleapp>
</target>
```

An additional setting like preloaderClass="MyProject.Preloader" doesn't work. How to display the preloader screen in an App package? I don't need any other packages like .exe .dmg or .msi files. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have foud the solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<description>Create .app for test project.</description>

<target name="bundle-test">

    <taskdef    resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
                uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
                classpath=".:${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>

    <fx:deploy  nativeBundles="all" width="600" height="600" outdir="outputdir">
        <info   title="Viewer" 
                vendor="My Company"
                description="Viewer Application"
                copyright="My Company ..."/>

        <fx:application 
                name="Viewer"
                mainClass="myapp.Start"
                preloaderClass="helpers.FirstPreloader">
            <fx:argument>ide=false</fx:argument>
            <fx:argument>app=true</fx:argument>
        </fx:application>

        <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}">
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Xms512m"/>
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m"/>
        </fx:platform>

        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="dist">
                <include name="Viewer.jar"/>
                <include name="lib/*.jar"/>
            </fx:fileset>
        </fx:resources>

    </fx:deploy>

    <delete file="outputdir/null.html"/>
    <delete file="outputdir/null.jnlp"/>
    <delete file="outputdir/Viewer.jar"/>
    <delete file="outputdir/bundles/Viewer-1.0.dmg"/>
    <delete file="outputdir/bundles/Viewer-1.0.pkg"/>
    <delete dir="outputdir/lib"/>

</target>
```